# Installing 16.04.2 LTS from USB - USB not recognised as boot option

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, live-usb

I'm running Windows 10 on an HP Envy laptop and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 as a dual-boot alongside Windows.
I already have Ubuntu14.04 installed but that operating system is broken and seems unfix-able so I want to reinstall. I'm hoping to just overwrite it with a new 16.04 install.

I used Rufus to burn the Ubuntu16.04 IOS to a USB drive.
However, when I restart my computer and select the 'boot from USB' option I get an error message saying 'the boot device did not work'.

I've tried this with Universal-USB-Installer instead of Rufus, I've tried it with GPT and MBR partition types, I've tried it with a Kingston2.0 USB and an Apacer 3.1 USB, I've tried it with a 14.04 IOS instead of 16.04, I've tried it with Boot Security disabled and I've tried it with Legacy Configuration enabled.
Nothing works.

I need an Ubuntu OS running on my laptop for a University project. Please help.

I'm aware that this is a duplicate question but looking at previous answers didn't help me.

Comment: Have you tried other options? My laptop sometimes shows bootable USB disk under HDD boot option. Please also check all other available boot options, one of them may work for your USB drive. Also if you have a USB 2.0 slot, try using that. For creating bootable Ubuntu USB drives under windows I recommend you using LinuxLive USB Creator (http://www.linuxliveusb.com/). It always works for me.

Comment: Of your system is indeed UEFI, have you tried manually signing the USB bootloader (grub) from the BIOS? I know Acer laptops tend to require signed bootloaders (even with Secure Boot off, go figure), maybe HP does too.